# Simplify repetitive SELECT ... IN query

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I have a query of the form

```
SELECT a, b, c from Tbl where [conditions] IN
    (SELECT a from Tbl where [conditions]
        GROUP BY a HAVING COUNT(*) > N)
    ORDER BY a DESC, b LIMIT 100
```

`[conditions]` is basically a series of `AND` statements and `a` is a column with possible duplicates. Column `a` + `b` is a unique combination. Currently I am using the `GROUP BY` clause simply to get the `COUNT(*) > N` to work. I want to return rows for column entries that satisfy the `[conditions]` and have at least `N` rows. As you can see the query is basically the same as the conditions are repeated. What is a better way to achieve the above?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to specify the exact `RDBMS` name that you are using.

Comment: I am using a `RDBMS` based on `sqlite`

Comment: If it's at least N rows, it should be a `>=` you're using in the query

Comment: Ok I know that, the point of the question is how can I optimize/minimize this query so I don't need to essentially repeat `[conditions]` twice

Comment: what's exactly `[condition]` ?

Comment: `[conditions] IN (SELECT a FROM... )` is not significant, unless `a` is a boolean column, since `[conditions`] returns a boolean value.

Comment: A bunch of clauses like `a = a_val AND b = b_val ... AND z > z_val`

Comment: Ok how can I perform this query without the need for `SELECT .... IN SELECT ( ... )`

Comment: You can do a join on the inner query

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM Tbl
WHERE a IN
(SELECT a FROM Tbl
HAVING COUNT(*) > N AND CASE [conditions] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1
GROUP BY a, CASE [conditions] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
```

Not the best option I guess?

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM Tbl
WHERE a IN (
SELECT a FROM
( SELECT a,
CASE WHEN [conditions] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS con FROM Tbl ) T
WHERE con = 0 
HAVING COUNT(*) > N
GROUP BY a, con);
```